# Need Help sequence of functions/ convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Problem:**

> Prove that the sequence of functions $\{ f_n \}$ defined by:
>   $f_n(x)= n \sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2n^2+x^2})$ converges uniformly on $[ 0, \alpha]$ where $\alpha > 0$. Does $\{ f_n \}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Here is what I did: I proved that the pointwise limit of $\{ f_{n} \}$ is the function $f( x ) = \frac{x^2}{4\pi}$. Then, in order to prove the uniform convergence, I need to prove that $$ \sup_{x\in [ 0, \alpha] } \left \{ | f_n (x)- f(x) |  \right \} \to 0 ,$$  as $n \to \infty  $ and that's where I am stuck. In the book, there is a hint saying that for $x$ in the mentioned interval $x \in [ 0, \alpha]$, and using the inequality $\sin x \geqslant x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$, 
we get: 
$$ \left| n \sin \sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2+x^2}  -\frac{x^2}{4\pi} \right| \leqslant \frac{a^2}{4\pi } \left ( 1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}}+1} \right ) + \frac{n}{3!} \frac{\alpha^6}{8n^3 \pi^3} .$$

I don't understand how the book got this inequality based on $\sin x \geqslant x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ for $x \geqslant 0$. Can anyone give me a detailed proof how to get that inequality given by the book? From that point, I can easily prove the uniform convergence.

For the uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$, there is hint saying that I should use $| \sin x | \leqslant \left | x \right |$ to get:
$$ \left| n \sin\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2+x^2} \ -\frac{x^2}{4\pi}\right| \geqslant 
\frac{x^2}{4\pi} \left( 1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}}+1} \right) .$$

Any help please how can we derive the last inequality too? because from this inequality, I can easily prove the non-uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If any of you guys reading this post, please I am waiting your answers or comments. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uniform convergence over $[0, \alpha]$.** I presume you are trying the apply the inequality to bound the given expression directly. Though this is *correct*, this is not *useful* because the inequality $\sin \theta \geqslant \theta - \frac{\theta^3}{3!}$ ($\theta \geqslant 0$) is tight only for small $\theta$, whereas the expression inside the "sin" grows unbounded in our case. So we massage the function a little before employing the inequality.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2})

&=& 
\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} - 2 n \pi)

\\ &=& 
\sin \left(\frac{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2 - (2 n \pi)^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} \right)

\\ &=& 
\sin \left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} \right).

\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Notice that $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi}$ is small, so we can hope to apply the inequality at this stage. Doing so gives
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} 

&\geqslant& \sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) 

\\ &\geqslant& \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} - \frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} \right)^3.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Try to take it from here.

*EDIT: More steps added.* The left hand side inequality implies that 
$$
\frac{x^2}{4\pi} - n\sin(\sqrt{4 \pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) \geqslant 0,
$$
so we only need to upper bound the difference. For this, we use the right hand side inequality:
$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2}{4 \pi} - n\sin(\sqrt{4 \pi^2 n^2 + x^2})

&\leqslant& \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} - \frac{n x^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} + \frac{n x^6}{6 (\color{Green}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi})^3}

\\ &\leqslant& \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} - \frac{nx^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} + \frac{nx^6}{6 (\color{Green}{4n\pi})^3}

\\ &\leqslant& \color{Red}{\frac{x^2}{4 \pi}} \left[ 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{4 \pi^2n^2}} + 1} \right] + \color{Red}{\frac{nx^6}{6 (4n\pi)^3}}

\\ &\leqslant& \color{Red}{\frac{{\alpha}^2}{4 \pi}} \left[ \color{Blue}{ 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{4 \pi^2n^2}} + 1} } \right] + \color{Red}{\frac{n{\alpha}^6}{6 (4n\pi)^3}}

\\ &\leqslant& \frac{\alpha^2}{4 \pi} \left[ \color{Blue}{ 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{\alpha^2}{4 \pi^2n^2}} + 1}} \right] + \frac{n\alpha^6}{6 (4n\pi)^3},
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
repeatedly using the fact that $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \alpha$.

---

**Non-uniform convergence over $[0, \infty)$.** We saw that
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) 
&\leqslant& \frac{nx^2}{\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2} + 2 n \pi} 
\\ &=& \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{4\pi^2n^2}} + 1} .
\end{eqnarray*}
$$ 
Can you get the inequality claimed by the hint from here?

*EDIT: More hints on the non-uniform convergence.* This problem is meant to highlight the (subtle at first glance) difference between pointwise and uniform convergence. For any fixed $x$, as $n \to \infty$, it is true that the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$; but this is what pointwise convergence is about.

If we want to show uniform convergence, we need to show that the sequence
$$
u_n := \sup \{ |f_n(x) - f(x)| \colon x \in \mathbb R \}
$$
goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. The idea is to provide a *uniform* upper bound on the error term $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ that is independent of $x \in \mathbb R$, such that the upper bound goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

In our example, we are interested in the sequence 
$$
\left| n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) - \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} \right| = \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} - n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) .
$$
To prove non-uniform convergence (over $[0, \infty)$), we need to lower bound the sequence
$$
u_n := \sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \left( \frac{x^2}{4 \pi} - n\sin (\sqrt{4\pi^2 n^2 + x^2}) \right) .
$$
By the inequality given to you in the text-book hint, we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_n 

&\geqslant& 
\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \frac{x^2}{4\pi} \left ( 1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2n^2}}+1} \right) .

\\ &\geqslant& 
\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \frac{x^2}{4\pi} \left ( 1-\frac{2}{\Big(\frac{|x|}{2 n \pi} \Big)} \right) .

\\ &=& 
\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \left( \frac{x^2}{4\pi} - n|x| \right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Taking $x = 8 n \pi$, we get 
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_n 
\geqslant
\frac{64 n^2 \pi^2}{4 \pi} - n \cdot 8 n \pi = 8 n^2 \pi \to \infty,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, clearly, $u_n$ cannot approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$. In fact, by choosing $x$ a little more carefully,* you can show that $u_n=\infty$ for each $n$.

*Note: Notice that our choice of $x$ varies as $n$ varies. This is unavoidable  because we already know that for any fixed $x$, the above deviation term goes to $0$.

Comment: I am still not able to reach the final answer based on your hint. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I just need one more step to finish my proof: for non-uniform convergence on $ mathbb R$, using your provided hint, I could prove the second inequality given in the statement of the problem (the one given as a hint by the book to prove non-uniform converegence). I think that the idea is to prove that right hand side doesn't tend to zero as n tends to infinity.

Comment: But, actually as n tends to infinity, the right hand side tends tends to zero, and thus the left hand side of the inequality is greater than or equal to 0 which is not sufficient to prove non uniform convergence, because I need it to be strictly greater than 0. Can you, help me out with this one? and Thanks for all the hints you gave so far.

Comment: @Zi2 Precisely. In fact, for any $n$, the right hand side is unbounded (so that, sup over all $x \in \mathbb R$ is infinity). [More explicitly, given $n$, take $x = 2 \pi n$ and see what happens to the difference.]

Comment: Indeed. The right hand side is unbounded which makes it clear now that the convergence cannot be uniform. Thanks again.